# Sending email from nodemailer for nodejs

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

When I try to send email from nodemailer I get an error: EAUTH API
I've tried to use both Hotmail and Gmail as my services as I understand from the documentation that if Gmail doesn't work, don't use it. However this does not appear to be the problem.

I want to use this email to enable forgot password in my App

The code:

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Hotmail',
  auth: {
    user: email,
    pass: pass
  }
});

router.post('/forgotpassword', function(req, res){
            async.waterfall([
                function(done) {
                    User.findOne({
                        email: req.body.email
                    }).exec(function(err, user) {
                        if (user) {
                            done(err, user);
                        } else {
                            done('User not found.');
                        }
                    });
                },
                function(user, done) {
      // create the random token
      crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buffer) {
        var token = buffer.toString('hex');
        done(err, user, token);
      });
  },
  function(user, token, done) {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: user._id }, { reset_password_token: token, reset_password_expires: Date.now() + 86400000 }, { upsert: true, new: true }).exec(function(err, new_user) {
        done(err, token, new_user);
    });
  },
  function(token, user, done) {
    var data = {
        to: user,
        from: email,
        template: 'forgot-password-email',
        subject: 'Password help has arrived!',
        context: {
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/user/reset_password?token=' + token,
            name: req.body.email
        }
    };

    smtpTransport.sendMail(data, function(err) {
        if (!err) {
            return res.json({ message: 'Kindly check your email for further instructions' });
        } else {
            return done(err);
        }
    });
  }
  ], function(err) {
    return res.status(422).json({ message: err });
  });
        });
```

My email and password are correct.

The error from postman is

> {"message":{"code":"EAUTH","command":"API"}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you should update your code and require one module for sending:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  service: 'Hotmail',
  auth: {
    user: email,
    pass: pass
  }
}));
```

As a security precaution, Google may require you to complete an additional step called Unlock Captcha when signing into a new device or application.

You might need to manually allow access to your Google account.

Login to your Google account using a browser, then visit the link below to unlock it: [click here](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

After clicking Allow button, you should see the message:

**Account access enabled. Please try signing in to your Google account again from your new device or application.**

and allow to less secure apps access: [less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

i test it, work for me

Answer (score 1):

1- to use Hotmail smtp configuration

```
   var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com", // hostname
       secureConnection: false, // TLS requires secureConnection to be false
       port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
      tls: {
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
      },
     auth: {
        user: 'mymail@outlook.com',
         pass: 'myPassword'
        }
  });
```

Or using built-in service

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
  service: "hotmail",
  auth: {
    user: "user@hotmail.com",
    pass: "password"
  }
 });
```

Ps. make sure that your user name and password is correct, and Hotmail not blocking your connection for security issues.

2- you can use service gmail,  but you have to [allow less secure connection to your Gmail](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

That error means your password or email is incorrect, Please check once.

also, you can visit the link below to switch less security

[link](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/lesssecureapps)https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/lesssecureapps